# Select 1024*1024*1024*1024 fails

Tags: sql-server

Can someone explain why `SELECT` of integer multiplication fails?

```
SELECT 1024*1024*1024*1024 -- ERROR
```

Is it due to the multiplication result becoming bigger than the `INT` datatype threshold?

```
DECLARE @VAL AS BIGINT
SET @VAL = 1024 -- OK
SET @VAL = 1024*1024 -- OK
SET @VAL = 1024*1024*1024 -- OK
SET @VAL = 1024*1024*1024*1024 -- ERROR
SET @VAL = 1099511627776 -- OK - 1024*1024*1024*1024=1099511627776
SET @VAL = CAST((1024*1024*1024*1024) AS BIGINT) -- ERROR
```

**Error Message**

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

[int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx)

> **Caution**
>
> When you use the +, -, *, /, or % arithmetic operators to perform implicit or explicit conversion of int, smallint, tinyint, or bigint constant values to the float, real, decimal or numeric data types, the rules that SQL Server applies when it calculates the data type and precision of the expression results differ depending on whether the query is autoparameterized or not.
>
> Therefore, similar expressions in queries can sometimes produce different results. When a query is not autoparameterized, the constant value is first converted to numeric, whose precision is just large enough to hold the value of the constant, before converting to the specified data type. For example, the constant value 1 is converted to numeric (1, 0), and the constant value 250 is converted to numeric (3, 0).
>
> When a query is autoparameterized, the constant value is always converted to numeric (10, 0) before converting to the final data type. When the / operator is involved, not only can the result type's precision differ among similar queries, but the result value can differ also. For example, the result value of an autoparameterized query that includes the expression SELECT CAST (1.0 / 7 AS float) will differ from the result value of the same query that is not autoparameterized, because the results of the autoparameterized query will be truncated to fit into the numeric (10, 0) data type.

Comment: Yeah, well that is what an Arithmetic Overflow is, running out of memory to store the result.

Comment: The error message seems pretty obvious - "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int." Presumably, an int is 32 bit, and 1024^4 == (2^10)^4 == 2^40 exceeds the range of a 32 bit Integer (2^32)

Comment: `SELECT CAST(1024 AS BIGINT) * 1024 * 1024 *1024` <- SQL Server casts constants without decimal values (1024) as integers if they fit. Cast one of the values explicitly to force SQL Server to use BIGINT.

Comment: Try `select SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(CONVERT(sql_variant,1099511627776),'BaseType')` to see why your `select 1099511627776` works, but not in the way you possible thought it did.

Comment: Thanks Damien, but why does select SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(CONVERT(sql_variant,1024*1024*1024*1024.0),'BaseType') return numeric and not float?

Comment: Because `1024.0` is a numeric constant, not a float one. See [Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms179899.aspx): "**decimal** constants are represented by a string of numbers that are not enclosed in quotation marks and contain a decimal point... **float** and **real** constants are represented by using scientific notation." (`decimal` and `numeric` are interchangable)

Comment: @Damien Thanks for sharing! I have learnt much, much more after asking this question on SO.

Answer (score 4):

Because 1024 is an int. SQL-Server takes first data type to make the arithmetic function.

A term is evaluated from left to right.

If you write 1099511627776 it is a numeric value.

Cast the first value into bigint (or numeric), then it works:

```
select cast(1 as bigint)*1024*1024*1024*1024
```

Comment: "it is a bigint" - No it isn't. It's a `numeric`. See sample posted in comment to question.

Comment: Yes, you are right - it numeric(13,0) - i correct my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, SQL will use the type INT by default to complete the operations. This explains why you'll get the error if the resulting value overflows the INT's maximum capacity (2,147,483,647).

A workaround could be to store the number you use in your operations in a BIGINT varialbe as such:

```
DECLARE @NUMBER AS BIGINT = 1024
DECLARE @VAL AS BIGINT
SET @VAL = @NUMBER
SET @VAL = @NUMBER*@NUMBER
SET @VAL = @NUMBER*@NUMBER*@NUMBER
SET @VAL = @NUMBER*@NUMBER*@NUMBER*@NUMBER
SET @VAL = 1099511627776
SET @VAL = CAST((@NUMBER*@NUMBER*@NUMBER*@NUMBER) AS BIGINT)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just found a query that does not throw an error after more googling; if I convert one of the values to decimal/numeric i.e. 1024.0

see [TSQL Arithmetic overflow using BIGINT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018788/tsql-arithmetic-overflow-using-bigint)

```
SELECT 1024*1024*1024*1024.0 -- OK
DECLARE @VAL AS BIGINT
SET @VAL = 1024 -- OK
SET @VAL = 1024*1024 -- OK
SET @VAL = 1024*1024*1024 -- OK
SET @VAL = 1024*1024*1024*1024.0 -- OK
SET @VAL = 1099511627776 -- OK

select SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(CONVERT(sql_variant,1024.0),'BaseType')  -- numeric
select SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(CONVERT(sql_variant,1024*1024*1024*1024.0),'BaseType')   -- numeric
```

Comment: FLOAT is not a precise data type, be careful with it!

Comment: Does this mean it will introduce precision errors? How do I find out more about this?

Comment: Yes, it may produce precision errors. Read the article about float and real data types in the doc. Search for SQL Server precision error on SO or using your favourite search engine to find some examples. Here is one of the questions from SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199371/sql-server-precision-crazyness